# git-svn fetch/rebase failing after trying to repair a corrupted file

Tags: git, git-svn

I recently had a corrupted object in my repository, pointing on my HEAD (the object was empty) . It happened after interrupting a git-svn command.  Then, I restored my repository by changing manually the refs on this object.

Now, I want to synchronize my git repository with SVN, but git svn fetch returns:

```
fatal: Invalid revision range 5a5dc92cd3083960fb4828ae387a32cda0554fa8..refs/remotes/a-branch
rev-list --pretty=raw --no-color --reverse 5a5dc92cd3083960fb4828ae387a32cda0554fa8..refs/remotes/a-branch --: command returned error: 128
```

5a5dc92cd3083960fb4828ae387a32cda0554fa8 refers to the corrupted object, I would like to say git-svn not to consider this object but another one, but I do not know how to hack this.

If anyone knows where/how git-svn internally stores this value it would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you have svn metadata stored with your commit messages (those `http://svn.…./svn/trunk@r12331 (<id>)`), you can delete the `.rev_map.<id>` files from the `.git/svn/…` directories.

git-svn will then re-create them before running the next command.

Edit:
When running `git gc` if you see output along the lines of:

```
$ git gc
warning: reflog of 'HEAD' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/heads/master' references pruned commits
warning: reflog of 'refs/remotes/trunk' references pruned commits
```

Then you know that you need to perform the above trick. In this case:

```
rm .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.*
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it clearer that the <id> in the rev_map comes from the previous reference, since I worked out what was needed from another reference on the web.