# Git SVN - Invalid revision range

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using git together with SVN.

I am trying to perform `git svn dcommit` but it gives me this error:

> $ git svn dcommit fatal: Invalid revision range
>   20edee48314fb1d070d84c1641abd5489d9a1479..refs/remotes/git-svn
>   rev-list --pretty=raw --reverse
>   20edee48314fb1d070d84c1641abd5489d9a1479..refs/remotes/git-svn --:
>   command returned error: 128

I can't seem to understand whats wrong.
I can't even do a git svn info. It gives me the same error

Comment: Does it really type 'rem otes' with a space inside? Don't you have such spaces in .git/config in a corresponding [svn-remote] section?

Comment: I highly doubt it. Everything looks fine in git/config

Comment: In order just not to lose your changes you may try to push your work with SmartGit which is git-svn-compatible but has independent implementation. Maybe after pushing everything will be ok again. Or maybe try to upgrade git version.

Comment: I was already using 1.7.0, but fine, I will try to upgrade to 1.7.1, but I highly doubt it will help.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.7.1 made it even worse. There is a bug in 1.71 with git SVN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-svn fetch/rebase failing after trying to repair a corrupted file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282377/git-svn-fetch-rebase-failing-after-trying-to-repair-a-corrupted-file)